# Issues reading zip containing UTF-8 xml files

Tags: python, utf-8, zip

I have zip archives containing many UTF-8 xml files.  These files have mostly English tags and text but a few tags contain non-English text.  I have no problem with opening the zip file, and parsing the xml files inside of it, but the non-English text looses it's encoding.

When an xml file is extracted and opened in Notepad++ the non-English text looks like:

```
Курс карбованца к доллару не изменился на Украинской Межбанковской Валютной Бирже (УМВБ) - 176.100.
```

When it is extracted and read in Python (on a linux box) the text looks like:

```
ÐÑÑÑ ÐºÐ°ÑÐ±Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½ÑÐ° Ðº Ð´Ð¾Ð»Ð»Ð°ÑÑ Ð½Ðµ Ð¸Ð·Ð¼ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ð»ÑÑ Ð½Ð° Ð£ÐºÑÐ°Ð¸Ð½ÑÐºÐ¾Ð¹ ÐÐµÐ¶Ð±Ð°Ð½ÐºÐ¾Ð²ÑÐºÐ¾Ð¹ ÐÐ°Ð»ÑÑÐ½Ð¾Ð¹ ÐÐ¸ÑÐ¶Ðµ (Ð£ÐÐÐ) - 176.100.
```

My code looks like:

```
def parse(self, fp):
    # open/decompress zip file
    with zipfile.ZipFile(fp, 'r') as f:
        # get all files in zip
        comp_files = f.namelist()
        for comp_file in comp_files:
            cfp = f.open(comp_file, 'r')
            # parse xml
            tree = ElementTree.parse(cfp)
            ...parsing...
```

I have tried decoding/encoding the text from cfp and wrapping it with codecs.EncodedFile() and input encoding of utf_8 and utf_8_sig with no change.  What can I do to fix the non-English text?

Comment: without the actual file it may be a problem to troubleshoot this one. I'd suggest you try checking what happens when you change the files' opening mode to binary ('rb')

Comment: I also did a test and couldn't duplicate your issue so it is VERY possible that the issue is that the original files saved don't set the files' encoding correctly. Have you tried unzipping the files by hand and checking what they look like in "less"? If they don't look right there you may need to verify the other end of the proces (when they are created and compressed)

Comment: @Toote The files are from a corpus so I cannot post the full files or change the process that they are created with.  Extracting them and running less gave a similar string encountered in Python `ÐÑÑÑ ÐºÐ°ÑÐ±Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½ÑÐ° Ðº Ð´Ð¾Ð»Ð»Ð°ÑÑ Ð½Ðµ`.  Even so, I was able to read them properly in Notepad++ which used the Encoding 'Encode UTF-8 without BOM'. Python has this in its codecs `utf_8_sig`.  I'll try opening in binary mode, but I believe there should be some way to do it through encodings.

Comment: that is really strange, it is not double-encoded UTF-8, nor koi8-r... УМВБ becomes 5 bytes Ð£ÐÐÐ, seems to be broken beyond belief :D

Comment: is it because you at some point handle the zip file on windows and not in binary mode?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result you are seeing is UTF-8 incorrectly decoded as latin-1/iso-8859-1:

```
>>> x=u'Курс карбованца к доллару не изменился на Украинской Межбанковской Валютной Бирже (УМВБ) - 176.100.'
>>> print x.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
ÐÑÑÑ ÐºÐ°ÑÐ±Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½ÑÐ° Ðº Ð´Ð¾Ð»Ð»Ð°ÑÑ Ð½Ðµ Ð¸Ð·Ð¼ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ð»ÑÑ Ð½Ð° Ð£ÐºÑÐ°Ð¸Ð½ÑÐºÐ¾Ð¹ ÐÐµÐ¶Ð±Ð°Ð½ÐºÐ¾Ð²ÑÐºÐ¾Ð¹ ÐÐ°Ð»ÑÑÐ½Ð¾Ð¹ ÐÐ¸ÑÐ¶Ðµ (Ð£ÐÐÐ) - 176.100.
```

I saved the following text encoded via Notepad++ as as a single file encoded as UTF-8 without BOM in a zipfile:

```
<text>Курс карбованца к доллару не изменился на Украинской Межбанковской Валютной Бирже (УМВБ) - 176.100.</text>
```

Your code with modifications to make it runable:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import zipfile

def parse(fp):
    # open/decompress zip file
    with zipfile.ZipFile(fp, 'r') as f:
        # get all files in zip
        comp_files = f.namelist()
        for comp_file in comp_files:
            cfp = f.open(comp_file, 'r')
            # parse xml
            tree = ElementTree.parse(cfp)
            print tree.getroot().text
            print type(tree.getroot().text)

parse(open('file.zip'))
```

The result:

```
Курс карбованца к доллару не изменился на Украинской Межбанковской Валютной Бирже (УМВБ) - 176.100.
<type 'unicode'>
```

So it looks to me that it is just being displayed incorrectly on your Linux box, but without an actual sample of the files you are working with, it is difficult to analyze further.

Comment: This was partially correct.  For one I wasn't running putty with UTF-8.  However the files still would not output with the right encoding (checked on another machine).  I did some reading and installed Russian UTF-8 locales on my Linux machine and it output the json correctly.